# Integrate content from API with a CMS website

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, ecm

I don't have lots of experience with Wordpress, Joomla, or any other PHP CMS for that matter. But I do know how to build a JSON RESTful API. In this particular case I've created one that handles creative content (articles, events data etc.)

Now I would like to create websites that consume this data. Each website can be a campaign website that retrieves its articles from a central repository a.k.a. the API. I can create content channels in the API that serve as a content pipeline for one particular website.

Normally I would create a website from scratch using HTML/JS and CSS. But I also recognize the benefits that comes with a popular CMS. You can add plugins along-side the articles etc, use tools like varnish and lot of SEO stuff.

What I don't want to do is duplicate the article content to an MySQL database. The articles should be managed outside the campaign websites. I would be very interested in anyone who has experience with a similar challenge, or anyone who might know an elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Joomla has a nice http api that you can use to consume REST data. What you might want to do is to create a simple component that would be in charge of rendering.  YOu can see a little bit about how it works if you look in `/libraries/joomla/github` or any of the other specific REST consuming packages.  There are some other options as well but it really depends on your data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do a similar thing with only two sites (Joomla). Basically i have a server where the articles where stored and two hosted domains. I did it with different techniques on the two sites (just for testing) and both work great for a long time.

The first page render the articel items trough a rss-feed (basically xml).
The second domain do this via JSONP. As i said both of them do not use their databeses to store articles in their categories, they just display content via http requests and formated data.

Comment: So in one example you do server-side rendering with RSS and the other is done client-side using JSONP?. 
Did you create a custom article type to accomplish this?

Comment: no both are server side. the rss is a url that i parse und the json basically too. i havent external access to the databases, otherwise i would do it in this way. as i said for me it worked good. in my php script i grab the data (xml rendring for feed or file_get_contents for the json data) and built my data-object-array to display the data.

Comment: Ok. Sounds interesting. But is your CMS completely oblivious to the articles as content entities? Or can you, for example, use an SEO plugin together with your content from JSONP or RSS?

Comment: Again: Joomla builts datarrays in each module/component for output. I do the same with one difference. The data didnt came from joomlas DB, The data came from other sources but at this point forward the normal joomla outputs are working. I built the same objects-array as the joomla db-funtion do but only not from db! And yes you can use any other plugin expect those wich are getting data direct from the db. but content-replace plugins are working, seo plugins working (cos mostly they affect menu items and no articles itself)...and so on.

Comment: sure there are some limitations but only for extensions that use data directly from db, but as i said most estensions use the well documented joomal developer functions and they mostly affect the prepaired data arrays.